# Monitoring VirtualProtect API using Microsoft Detours or Alternative Methods

Tags: c++, windows, monitoring, detours

Is it possible to monitor the VirtualProtect API in the system using the Detours library provided by Microsoft, and if so, could you provide guidance or examples on how to achieve this? Alternatively, are there other recommended methods or libraries for effectively monitoring the VirtualProtect API?

I tried creating two different exe's in which one have detours functionality which keeps on running in background and other exe have virtualprotect API sample program, but it didn't monitor the sample program of virtualprotect API.